# What to do to reduce the humming noise of an AC unit?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have this ac unit:
[image]

When I turn it on it makes a noise as soon as compressor starts. It's a humming repetitive noise. I thought it was the fan, but when I put it in fan only mode it does not make the noise. Now when the compressor is on, it makes normal noise but lately it started to get a little louder with the repetitive humming. I want to attempt to reduce it by opeining it up and tighteing the screws, oiling what I can ...etc. My question, is what else can I do?

Comment: run it while open and CAREFULLY feel different parts (maybe with a glove on) for vibration, which is what causes the sound. Once located, kill the vibrations with poster putty, caulk, hotglue, foam wedges, wadded up latex gloves, whatever's handy. you can line the box with dynamat or thin carpet as well.

Comment: Thanks that's what I did and I reduced the noise. Some of the copper pipes (not sure if copper) where transferring the vibration from the compressor I think. Wrapped one pipe in a bit of insulation foam and the noise is much better.